# Clicking OK in a prompt

Tags: javascript, alert, confirm

I know how to *create* alerts and confirm boxes, but what I cannot find out how to do is to do the actual clicking of OK.  I have a page that pops up a confirm box.  **I** want to click OK using a Java Script add-on.  Basically, I want my code to click a link on the page, then click ok when prompted.  Is that possible?

Comment: To what end? If the code is doing the click, why bother with the confirm?

Comment: @JoelEtherton. Maybe it's a confirm for the programmer... ? `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible with a browser pop-up.

However if it's a modal dialog that sits within the DOM of the page, then you can trigger a JavaScript event to close it. An example of such a dialog is [jQuery's dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Comment: Thanks.  That's the impression I was getting.  :(